# Still cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, opencv

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private IplImage frame;
    private IplImage imgMain;
    private CvCapture VideoCapture;
    private IplImage frames;


    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double vidWidth, vidHeight;

        if (btnVideo.Text.CompareTo("Start Video") == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                VideoCapture = cvlib.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);


                if (VideoCapture == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
                    return;
                }

                btnVideo.Text = "Stop Video";

                cvlib.cvSetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, cvlib.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
                cvlib.cvSetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, cvlib.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);

                frames = cvlib.cvQueryFrame(VideoCapture);

                vidWidth = cvlib.cvGetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, cvlib.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
                vidHeight = cvlib.cvGetCaptureProperty(VideoCapture, cvlib.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

                CamImageBox.Width = (int)vidWidth;
                CamImageBox.Height = (int)vidHeight;

                timerGrab.Interval = 1000;
                timerGrab.Enabled = true;


            }
            catch (Exception excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            btnVideo.Text = "Start Video";
            timerGrab.Enabled = false;

            if (VideoCapture == null)
            {
                cvlib.cvReleaseImage(frames);
                VideoCapture = null;
            }
        }


    }

    private void timerGrab_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame = cvlib.cvQueryFrame(VideoCapture);

        if (frame == null)
        {
            timerGrab.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("failed");
            return;
        }

        imgMain = cvlib.cvCreateImage(cvlib.cvSize(640, 480), 8, 3);

        CamImageBox.Image = cvlib.ToBitmap(imgMain, false);

        cvlib.cvReleaseImage(imgMain);

    }

}
```

i changed the library that i used.

it is now cvwrappercs230 it is a wrapper for opencv in c#..

also it said that the cvwrappercpp230 was unable to load the dll of it. System.DLLNotfoundexception even though the dll is in the folder.

the problem is now it is not giving me a black screen instead of it gives now a gray screen..

and the problem when i break it is in the `Application.Run(new MainForm());`

i also changed the interval to 1000 because someone says that 42 is too low but i still dont know where the problem is..

but when i changed the interval to 42 again.

the problem of the  break point is back to `frame = cvlib.cvQueryFrame(videocapture)`

Comment: just out of curiosity, which wrapper lib are you using ?

Comment: i mean the wrapper i used is cvwrappercs230

Comment: @berak the wrapper lib i used is cvwrapcs230 or cvwrap230d a wrapper for opencv c#.